# Set the Caption of label to Username

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I'm making an Access database and have a secure logon feature. I want to use the Username that is entered in a Label or other control as a "Sign in as " feature.

How do I reference the other form that is not my Sign in form?

I want to attach the ID or User name to Label 66 in form UserViewForm.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim User As String
Dim UserLevel As Integer
Dim TempPass As String
Dim ID As Integer
Dim UserName As String
Dim TempID As String

If IsNull(Me.TxtUserName) Then
 MsgBox "Please enter UserName", vbInformation, "Username required"
 Me.TxtUserName.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.TxtPassword) Then
 MsgBox "Please enter Password", vbInformation, "Password required"
 Me.TxtPassword.SetFocus
Else
 If (IsNull(DLookup("UserLogin", "tblUser", "UserLogin = '" & Me.TxtUserName.Value & "' And UserPassword = '" & Me.TxtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
 MsgBox "Invalid Username or Password!"
 Else
 TempID = Me.TxtUserName.Value
 UserName = DLookup("[UserName]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.TxtUserName.Value & "'")
 UserLevel = DLookup("[UserType]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.TxtUserName.Value & "'")
 TempPass = DLookup("[UserPassword]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.TxtUserName.Value & "'")
 UserLogin = DLookup("[UserLogin]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.TxtUserName.Value & "'")
 DoCmd.Close
 If (TempPass = "password") Then
 MsgBox "Please change Password", vbInformation, "New password required"
 DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUserinfo", , , "[UserLogin] = " & UserLogin
 Else
 'open different form according to user level
 If UserLevel = 1 Then ' for admin
 DoCmd.OpenForm "UserViewForm"
 'Else
 'DoCmd.OpenForm "Ne"
 End If
 End If
 End If
End If

Forms!UserViewFrom.Label66 = TempID

End Sub
```

This is for user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For labels, you need to set the `Caption` property.

```
Forms!UserViewFrom.Label66.Caption = TempID
```

Also note that you shouldn't store passwords in plaintext, nor use unsanitized user input to build SQL commands - look up SQL injection.